# How do you create a recursive function in a nested xml - PHP

Tags: php, xml, object, recursion

Greetings

does someone have some experience with recursive functions?

I'm trying to parse a XML-file into objects (in PHP)(for using it later in drupal)
The code that I'm writing is after the first "children" node practically always the same (see below).
the only 2 things that changes are the link from xpath (what shouldn't be that difficult) and creating dynamic objects-variable (if that exist).

*The code for the first subject (the whole thing is a course)*

'$item->ident  <-- is known because you are in a foreach

> $resulty =
>   $xpaths->xpath("/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[ident =
>   '$item->ident']/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type =
>   'bc']");
>
> ```
> foreach ($resulty as $itemy) {
>
>    $SubjectObject = new subject();
>
> // isnt 100% correct but doesn't matter now
>
>    $SubjectObject->getSubjectFolders($FolderObject);
>
>   $SubjectObject->setSubjectId(isset($item->SubjectId) ? (string) $item->SubjectId: null);
>   $SubjectObject->setSubjectShortTitle(isset($item->SubjectName) ? (string) $item->SubjectName: null);
>
>   $ChapterObject->setSubject($SubjectObject);
>  }
> ```

---

**Now - if i want the subject from a subject from a subject from a course than this would be**

$resulty = $xpaths->xpath("/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[ident = '$item->ident']/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type = 'bc']");

```
foreach ($resulty as $itemy) {

   $SubjectObject = new subject();

   $SubjectObject->getSubjectFolders($FolderObject);

  $SubjectObject->setSubjectId(isset($itemy->SubjectId) ? (string) $itemy->SubjectId: null);
  $SubjectObject->setSubjectShortTitle(isset($itemy->SubjectName) ? (string) $itemy->SubjectName: null);

        $resultz = $xpaths->xpath("/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[ident = '$item->ident']children/*[ident = '$itemy->ident']/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type = 'bc']");

            foreach ($resultz as $itemz) {

               $SubSubjectObject = new subject();

               $SubSubjectObject->getSubjectFolders($FolderObject);

              $SubSubjectObject->setSubjectId(isset($itemz->SubjectId) ? (string) $itemz->SubjectId: null);
              $SubSubjectObject->setSubjectShortTitle(isset($itemz->SubjectName) ? (string) $itemz->SubjectName: null);



                            $resulta = $xpaths->xpath("/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[ident = '$item->ident']/children/*[ident = '$itemy->ident']/children/*[ident = '$itemz->ident']/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type = 'bc']");

                                foreach ($resulta as $itema) {

                                   $SubSubSubSubjectObject= new subject();

                                   $SubSubSubSubjectObject->getSubjectFolders($FolderObject);

                                  $SubSubSubSubjectObject->setSubjectId(isset($itema->SubjectId) ? (string) $itema->SubjectId: null);
                                  $SubSubSubSubjectObject->setSubjectShortTitle(isset($itema->SubjectName) ? (string) $itema->SubjectName: null);


                                                  (and so on)


                                  $SubSubSubjectObject->setSubject($SubSubSubSubjectObject);
                                 }



              $SubjectObject->setSubject($SubSubjectObject);

          }


  $ChapterObject->setSubject($SubjectObject);
```

}

**here is the xml tree (example)**

```
<Structure>

    <rootnode>

        <CursusName>History</CursusName>
        <CursusId>100001</CursusId>
        <children>

            <childNode>

                 <SubjectName>World War 1</SubjectName>
                <SubjectId>100002</SubjectId>
                <children>

                    <childNode>

                         <SubjectName>World War 1.1</SubjectName>
                        <SubjectId>100016</SubjectId>
                        <children>

                            <childNode>

                                 <SubjectName>World War 1.1.1</SubjectName>
                                <SubjectId>100032</SubjectId>
                                <children>

                                    <childNode>

                                         <SubjectName>World War 1.1.1.1</SubjectName>
                                        <SubjectId>100065</SubjectId>
                                        </children>

                                    </childNode>

                                </children>
                                +<children></children>

                            </childNode>

                        </children>
                        +<children></children>

                    </childNode>
                    +<childNode></childNode>

                </children>
                +<children></children>

            </childNode>
            +<childNode></childNode>
            +<childNode></childNode>

        </children>
        +<visibility></visibility>
        +<accessibility></accessibility>

    </rootnode>
    <version>1</version>

</Structure>
```

**SO**

Can someone help mee?
Does someone know how I can fix the problem with the objects?
a kind of foreach/while loop thats create objects? and fetch them into his parent object?

sorry for the long post and all those lines of code

Kind regards

Dieter

Kind regards

Comment: I think you need to format your code properly...

Answer (score 0):

```
function recurseResults($resulty)
{
    foreach ($resulty as $itemy) 
    {
        $SubjectObject = new subject();
        $SubjectObject->getSubjectFolders($FolderObject);
        $SubjectObject->setSubjectId(isset($itemy->SubjectId) ? (string) $itemy->SubjectId: null);
        $SubjectObject->setSubjectShortTitle(isset($itemy->SubjectName) ? (string) $itemy->SubjectName: null);
        $resultz = $xpaths->xpath("/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/*[ident = '$item->ident']children/*[ident = '$itemy->ident']/children/*[type = 'st' or type = 'sp' or type = 'bc']");
        // __save my new subject somewhere__
        recurseResults($resultz);
    }
}
```